# Node js сохранение полученного zip архива

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip

С клиента получаю архив в base64, перевожу в utf, сохраняю, но архив оказывается битым. Ошибка и код ниже

```
function _decodeBase64ToUtf8(b64string) {
    var buffer;
    if (typeof Buffer.from === "function") {
        // Node 5.10+
        buffer = Buffer.from(b64string, 'base64');
    } else {
        // older Node versions
        buffer = new Buffer(b64string, 'base64');
    }

    return buffer;
}
let data = _decodeBase64ToUtf8(zipBase64)
fs.writeFileSync('banner.zip', data, function (e) {
        if (e) throw e

        console.log('saved!');

    })
```

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: А зачем делать преобразование? WriteFileSync и сам это может сделать. И где гарантия что исходные данные действительно были zip-архивом?

Comment: И, кстати, у writeFileSync нет колбека

Comment: Ну и проверять файл лучше не встроенным в винду, а нормальным архиватором типа winZip или winRar

Comment: Не смотря на все правки, вопрос ещё актуален

Comment: Не вижу правок. А вы комментарии читали вообще?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:
в функцию _decodeBase64ToUtf8 нужно передовать строку base64 без data:application/x-zip-compressed;base64,